# how to draw more than one graphs in the same plot

Tags: plot

I want a plotting script that will plot a multiple graphs on the same plot where the values of my data have the same x coordinate. This will help me the differences of each variable in the plot. I tried to plot using spreadsheet, but the plots are not clearly identifiable each other. I want you help me with the script to do my plot. My data looks like as follow

```
x y1 y2 y3 y4
1 10 25 28 30
2 20 15 40 20
3 10 10 30 20
4 2 5 15 30
.
.
.
.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify any preferences about the plotting program, so here is a version using [gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnuplot). Just run the following script

```
set terminal pdfcairo
set output 'output.pdf'

set style data linespoints
set key autotitle columnheader
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2, '' using 1:3, '' using 1:4, '' using 1:5
```

with the data file you posted (exactly like shown, including newlines and spaces, and column headers) I get:

[image]

You could of course also use another output format, e.g. `pdf`, which is more suitable for such line plots. Then just substitute the first two lines with:

```
set terminal pdfcairo
set output 'output.pdf'
```